# Add StartUp Parameters to PowerShell Profile

Tags: windows, powershell

I've recently started learning how to use PowerShell, specifically learning how to write a profile for myself.  I would like for it to launch in full screen mode (reached via ALT+ENTER) as I have a monitor set aside specifically to do things in it.  After doing some research online I found [this technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff629472.aspx) that states one could launch PowerShell with the -WindowStyle parameter to open a new instance of PowerShell with a certain window style (minimixed, hidden, etc.), among other parameters.

I tried adding this to my profile out of curiosity but, as expected, it caused an unending loop of continuously opening new instances of PS with the parameters I set.

Is there anything I could add to my profile so that it launches PowerShell in full screen mode?

I'm on Windows 10.

EDIT: I have tried adding 'mode 300' to the profile, it looks like it cause powershell to expand to the resolution of the screen.  Interestingly, because PS launches on a vertical monitor it doesn't actually maximize PS - it just expands like it would if the screen were in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut to `"%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe " -NoExit -Command "mode 300"`

(Change location of EXE as appropriate, the important thing is the mode 300 bit)

Comment: mode 300 seems to just maximize the window, not full screen it - I will add clarification to the question.